# Why does Spark only use one executor on my 2 worker node cluster if I increase the executor memory past 5 GB?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I am using a 3 node cluster: 1 master node and 2 worker nodes, using T2.large EC2 instances.

The "free -m" command gives me the following info:

**Master:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7733       6324       1409          0        221       4555
-/+ buffers/cache:       1547       6186
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

**Worker Node 1:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7733       3203       4530          0        185       2166
-/+ buffers/cache:        851       6881
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

**Worker Node 2:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7733       3402       4331          0        185       2399
-/+ buffers/cache:        817       6915
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

In the yarn-site.xml file, I have the following properties set:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>7733</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>7733</value>
</property>
```

In `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` I am setting the `spark.executor.cores` at `2` and `spark.executor.instances` at `2`.

When looking at the spark-history UI after running my spark application, both executors (1 and 2) show up in the "Executors" tab along with the driver. In the cores column on that same page, it says 2 for both executors.

When I set the executor-memory at 5G and lower, my spark application runs fine with both worker node executors running. When I set the executor memory at 6G or more, only one worker node runs an executor. Why does this happen? Note: I have tried increasing the yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb and it doesn't change this behavior.

Comment: Maybe because the input splits all fit in memory of one executor container?

Comment: You should not set your YARN sizes to be the entire machine, however . The OS still needs to run regular processes